# Iterate over table cells and insert data in an array

Tags: jquery

I need advice regarding a simple iteration.

I have several `.termeknev` elements. Some of them have simple text inside (they are `<td>` elements), some of them are `<input>` elements. Whatever the type is, I need it's text/value in an array.

This is my current code:

```
$('.termeknev').each(function () {
    if ($(this).val() === "") {
        termekek.push($(this).text());
    } else {
        termekek.push($(this).val());
    }
});
```

But I find it not pretty. Is there a way to make this cleaner or to simplify it?

Comment: In the each, the this variable will be a DOM object. Use `$.each(idx,obj)` and access object with `$(obj)` inside the loop.

Comment: That's about as clean and simple as it gets. You have differing interfaces that you're trying to combine - you're going to have to use their appropriate interfaces when doing so.

Comment: how about using DOM method this.value, instead of $(this).val(), so the if condition would look like this: if (this.value === "")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `val()` is only used for form controls I would suggest you test for type of element. The `value` of a `td` would be `undefined` which would throw off your current logic.

```
$('.termeknev').each(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':input') { /* pseudo selector will return any input, select, textarea etc */
        termekek.push($(this).val());
    } else {
        termekek.push($(this).text());
    }
});
```